# C# WebClient.DownloadString() Get specific part?

Tags: c#

I want to download a specif string from website but I am not sure how I achieve it the best way.

Right now I do it like this:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string htmlString = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    string encoding = WebUtility.UrlDecode(htmlString);
    Console.WriteLine(encoding);
}
```

However, this returns the whole webpage as a string, can I somehow only download a specific part of the URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "a specific part"? I strongly suspect the answer is "no" - you'll need to download the whole page, and then parse it.

Comment: I guess by saying "a specific part" you want to parse the html and then extract that specific part. For C# you can use https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse the downloaded html and use a css selector to get that specific thing. Not sure if this is what you want, thats why I am writing this as a comment

Comment: @adeel41 I'll look into that cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the webserver support byte serving (Accept-Ranges header) then you can access a part of the document.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7fy67z6d(v=vs.100).aspx
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support/